# namespace backward compatibility php

Tags: php, namespaces, rename

For the company i am working of we are developing a framework. Mainly with the intention to use indoors. But also for some side projects. Now we are in the process of opensource-ing it.

All classes in our framework are in a namespace prefixed with the name of the framework to have a distinct split between the project and the framework.

Now i run into the following problem: we want to re brand it as a part of making it open source.. And so we renamed the namespace.. For old projects we want to maintain backwards compatibility. So all classes should be accessible in the old namespace.

Does anyone have a solution to this, other than rewriting every class?

Comment: Interesting question. Hard to speculate without more context but I wonder if it would be possible to alias imported classes in some creative way

Comment: As @DarraghEnright mentioned, it might work by using aliases, but that could become painful. Specially if you add new classes to the framework. I would rather update the existing projects. It shouldn't be hard to refactor the namespaces with a proper IDE. It will probably be faster to do than trying to solve the two-namespace-issue.

Comment: Thinking about this a little, I'm inclined to agree @MagnusEriksson - it should be straightforward search-and-replace refactor, especially if all classes are imported fully as opposed to fully-qualified namespaces being used throughout code. The one caveat might be if there are a lot of legacy projects.

Comment: @Mark how do you do autoloading?

Comment: Just do a hard break to the new name and get over it. In the long run it's the path of least resistance/pain.

Comment: Auto loading is done through a class, most things are loaded through injection (@inject() annotations causes to load a class

As for the hard break.. i would prefer to do so. But there are some other systems working with the framework.. who want new features.. So having backwards compatibility, atleast untill they changed their software would be nice.